# On ios7, Spotify Login with Facebook View shown below Navigation Item

Tags: ios, spotify, facebook-login, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

So, I have this problem, basically the view controller appears below the navigation controller. This happens a lot in iOS 7, however, in this case I haven't been able to fix it with just `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone`, because I don't know for which view controller I should set this.

How could I solve this?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Create a `viewWillAppear` method in SPLoginViewController.m like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        UIViewController *internalLoginViewController = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        if (internalLoginViewController && [internalLoginViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        {
            [internalLoginViewController setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
        }
}
```

Apparently the view controller we want to target is the one at index 0 in the UINavigationController's view controllers (SPLoginViewController is a UINavigationController).

Answer (score 1):

By unchecking this in the viewcontroller property
[image]

just uncheck the Adjust Scroll View Insets and it will work fine.

Update:
Use this if you are not using xib/storyboard

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

Comment: Okay, but those are properties for XIB files. There are no xib files corresponding to the Facebook login in the cocoalibspotify framework. It's just `SPLoginViewController.m/.h`

Comment: i have updated my answer. please check and let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: Sorry, but are you familiar with the cocoalibspotify library, or are you answering my question in a general sense? Because the problem is that setting this on the SPLoginViewController object does nothing. That is the problem.

Comment: can you tell me in which controller you are calling the login controller.